# WildFly 8 can't connect to MySQL after restart

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8

My enviroment has the following servers: WildFly 8.0 and MySQL 5.5.32.

The database server is stopped and started every night for backup procedures. After that, I'm getting the following error in my WildFly Log:

```
09:52:38,136 ERROR [stderr] (default task-11) gate.error.APPLError: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
```

I have five configured datasources between these servers, but only one has this problem.

I'm not using JPA.